# Python loc multiindex series with repeated keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index Series defined like this:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], ["c", "d", "e"]]))
s
```

```
A  c    1
   d    2
   e    3
B  c    4
   d    5
   e    6
dtype: int64
```

I want to evaluate this series at two lists:

```
l1 = ['A', 'B', 'A']
l2 = ['c', 'd', 'c']
```

How can I do it pythonically without a for loop, e.g. without

```
[s.loc[x, y] for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
s.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([l1, l2])]
```

Output:

```
A  c    1
B  d    5
A  c    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: is there a chance you could explain why it's faster ?

Comment: @LaurentB.I can't say for sure, I guess because there is no reshaping involved since the levels behave like "columns" in a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply `zip()` into a `.loc[]`:

```py
print(s.loc[zip(l1, l2)])
```

Prints:

```
A  c    1
B  d    5
A  c    1
dtype: int64
```

---

If you want a list:

```py
print(s.loc[zip(l1, l2)].to_list())
```

Prints:

```
[1, 5, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks I like the solution! I've just noticed it is more than 10x slower than the for loop. Why is it so?

Comment: @user2743931 I'm assuming it's because `s.loc[zip(...)]` constructs a new `pd.Series` (with own index etc.) and with `s.loc[x, y]` you get only single value (and inside list-comprehension you construct a list directly)

Comment: I did `pd.Series([s.loc[x, y] for x, y in zip(l1, l2)], index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 'c'),('B', 'd'),('A', 'c')]))` and it is still much faster than the nice pythonic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Other writing style :

```py
import pandas as pd
import time
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], ["c", "d", "e"]]))

l1 = ['A', 'B', 'A']
l2 = ['c', 'd', 'c']

start = time.time()

r = s[zip(l1, l2)].tolist()

end = time.time()

print(end-start)
print(r)

# 0.0028162002563476562
# [1, 5, 1]
```

@Mozway approach seems to be faster

```
Timings :
# 1 - Mozway : 0.0019218921661376953
# 2 - Laurent B. & Andrej Kesely : average around # 0.0025...
```